# How to differentiate access to the API use WSO2?

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server, wso2-esb

I have WSO2 IS 5.3 and WSO2 ESB 5.0

For example:
Company 1 have bank account 123456
User of Company1 - user1 try access to REST API /api/accountinfo  ( on WSO2 ESB).
His send POST data "account=123456" and receives detail information about this bank account (123456)

Company 2 have bank account 654321
User of Company1 - user1 try access to REST API /api/accountinfo
His send POST data "account=123456" and recive detail information about this account (654321)

How i can do disable User2 get information about 123456 ?

Comment: can you check XACML using entitlement mediator with WSO2 ESB?

Comment: i think if you use WSO2 APIM, it would be the easy to build a solution. Basically protect your API with OAuth. And use the oauth token sent by a user when accessing the API to get details about him and handle based on that within your API logic

Comment: My be "Security Token Service Configuration" and UsernameToken can help? Where can i read about apply UsernameToken ?